# How do I customize / use a custom layout for the option displayed in the default view of a Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

In the app I am writing, I have a list of Integers that represent String resource IDs that I am using to make a Spinner.

I made a custom adapter and set up getDropDownView() to populate my Spinner's dropdown:

```
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int sortItem = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sort_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder.sortItemTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sort_item_textview);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.sortItemTv.setText(convertView.getResources().getString(sortItem));
    return convertView;
}
```

This works great for the dropdown itself, but the actual resource ID - an integer - is being displayed in the Spinner when the dropdown is collapsed.  I obviously want the String, not the resource ID.  Is there any way to use a custom layout or display to change that?  Do I need to make a custom Spinner?

Answer (score 0):

You must implement `getView` as well:

```
getView -> collapsedView
getDropDownView -> expanded items
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  I changed that method to a getCustomView method and returned it from both getView and getDropDownView.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
}

public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int sortItem = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sort_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder.sortItemTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sort_item_textview);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    viewHolder.sortItemTv.setText(convertView.getResources().getString(sortItem));
    return convertView;
}
```